# Spring Batch: MultiResourceItemWriter wrapping a CompositeItemWriter?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'm working with a new batch process on a legacy system. We are constrained by not using Spring Boot, and our Spring Batch version is 3.0.8.

The requirements are as follows:

1. Read records from a database - using a HibernateCursorItemReader for this
2. Minimal processing - not worried about this
3. Need 2 different writers:
   a. Write a max of 1K records to an XML file. Using a MultiResourceItemWriter here to create new XML files based on the chunk size.
   b. Write status information back to the database. This writer needs to know the filename used in the previous writer.

I'm using a CompositeItemWriter to add the two writers above as delegates:

```
  @Bean
  public CompositeItemWriter<Report> compositeItemWriter() throws Exception {
    CompositeItemWriter<Report> compositeItemWriter = new CompositeItemWriter<>();

    List<ItemWriter<? super Report>> writerDelegates = new ArrayList<>();
    writerDelegates.add(reportXMLWriter());
    writerDelegates.add(reportDatabaseWriter());
    compositeItemWriter.setDelegates(writerDelegates);
    compositeItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();

    return compositeItemWriter;
  }
```

The reportXMLWriter is a MultiResourceItemWriter that has its own delegate:

```
  @Bean
  public MultiResourceItemWriter<Report> reportXMLWriter() {

    MultiResourceItemWriter<Report> writer = new MultiResourceItemWriter<>();
    writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(new File(getDestination())));
    writer.setResourceSuffixCreator(new XMLSuffixCreator());
    writer.setDelegate(reportWriterDelegate());
    writer.setItemCountLimitPerResource(this.chunkSize);

    return writer;

  }
```

Both the reportWriterDelegate and the reportDatabaseWriter implement ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream:

```
public class ReportItemWriterDelegate implements ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream<Report> {

  @Override
  public void write(List<? extends Report> items) throws Exception {
  // writes XML files for the current chunk
  }
...
}

public class ReportDatabaseWriter implements ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream<Report> {


  @Override
  public void write(List<? extends Report> items) throws Exception {
   // writes status info back to the DB
   ...
  }
}
```

So far so good - now the questions:

I need to be able to write the file name (set in the ReportWriterDelegate resource at the beginning of each chunk) back to the database in the ReportDatabaseWriter.

I've tried setting the CompositeItemWriter (with it's delegates) as the delegate in the MultiResourceItemWriter. This would let both the xml and database writers have the resource set at the beginning of a chunk. Setting this up appeared straightforward, but now I now get a ClassCastException in the composite item writer with this config code:

```
  @Bean
  public ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream<? super Report> compositeItemWriter() throws  Exception{
    CompositeItemWriter<Report> compositeItemWriter = new CompositeItemWriter<>();

    List<ItemWriter<? super Report>> writerDelegates = new ArrayList<>();
    writerDelegates.add(reportWriterDelegate());
    writerDelegates.add(reportDatabaseWriter());
    compositeItemWriter.setDelegates(writerDelegates);
    compositeItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();

    return (ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream<? super InspectionReport>) compositeItemWriter;  
  }
```

The runtime error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.item.file.ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream
```

Also not entirely sure how I'd pass the current resource through the CompositeItemWriter to each of its delegates - maybe extend CompositeItemWriter to make it ResourceAware?

Should I keep the MultiResourceItemWriter as one of the CompositeItemWriter delegates? If so, how can I make the resource filename from the XML writer available in the ReportDatabaseWriter?

If you've read this far, thanks for sticking with me. I'd appreciate any comments about this.

Comment: `maybe extend CompositeItemWriter to make it ResourceAware?` I think this is the way to go, because it will give you access to the current resource in the composite writer and pass it to the delegates.

Comment: Thanks @Mahmoud Ben Hassine - that was exactly the right direction. I created a new ResourceAwareCompisiteItemWriter, and that was easier than I expected.

Comment: Great. Glad to hear your solved your issue.